# Write to an uint8_t using T

Tags: c++, arrays

I've a `std::uint8_t * bytes` member (`ByteArray#bytes`), but can't put an `T` value on it properly. So far I only tested writting an `int = 259` at index `0`, then I read it and got `3` as output.

http://rextester.com/HKU93771

**ByteArray.hh**

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2017 Uncloud Group. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * See ~/COPYRIGHT.md.
 */

#ifndef mutils_ByteArray_hh
#define mutils_ByteArray_hh

#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>

// (Endianness is detected at compile time, so...)
// (careful.)

#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    #define MUTILS_LE
#endif

static std::uint8_t * reversing;
static std::uint8_t i;
static std::uint8_t j;

namespace mutils
{
    // Dynamically-sized array of bytes.

    class ByteArray
    {
    public:
        // (Creates an empty ByteArray.)

        ByteArray() { SetLength(0); }

        ByteArray(std::size_t length)
        {
            bytes = nullptr;
            SetLength(length);
        }

        ~ByteArray()
        {
            std::free(bytes);
        }

        // Read little-endian value.

        template<typename T>
        inline T
        ReadLE(std::size_t index)
        {
            std::uint8_t s = bytes[index];

            #ifdef MUTILS_LE
                return T(s);
            #else
                return reverse<T>(&s);
            #endif
        }

        // Write value using little-endianness.
        // Note: No out-of-bounds check is done.

        template<typename T>
        inline void
        WriteLE(std::size_t index, T value)
        {
            #ifndef MUTILS_LE
                value = reverse(&value);
            #endif
            ((T&) bytes[index]) = value;
        }

        inline auto
        GetLength() { return length; }

        void
        SetLength(std::size_t len);

//      ByteArray
//      SliceView(std::size_t start_v, std::size_t end_v);

    private:
        std::uint8_t * bytes;
        std::size_t length;

        // Reverse the byte-order of a value.

        template<typename T>
        T
        reverse(std::uint8_t * value)
        {
            for (i = 0, j = sizeof(T); (--j) >= sizeof(T); ++i)
                reversing[j] = value[i];

            return T(*reversing);
        }
    };

} // namespace mutils

#endif // mutils_ByteArray_hh
```

**ByteArray.cc**

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2017 Uncloud Group. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * See ~/COPYRIGHT.md.
 */

#include <mutils/ByteArray.hh>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>

// Updates the array length.

void
mutils::ByteArray::SetLength(std::size_t len)
{
    if (len == 0) 
         bytes = nullptr;
    else bytes = (std::uint8_t *) realloc(bytes, len);

    length = len;
}
```

Test

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    mutils::ByteArray b(4);
    b.WriteLE<int>(0, 259);
    std::cout << b.ReadLE<int>(0) << "\r\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't be sure whether it's a real problem, but I don't see `reversing` ever have space allocated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `return T(s)` wrong, you don't want to construct a T from a byte. Look at WriteLE. Do you see a cast to `T*`? Why do you think it is needed there but not here?

Comment: @n.m. Looking-up [Explicit type conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast), `T ( s )` is equivalent to the `(T*) bytes` cast. (For me, it only constructs when `T` is a class. This is "non-sense".)

Comment: " T ( s ) is equivalent to the (T*) bytes cast." No it is absolutely not. What exact place in the linked document makes you think so?

Comment: @n.m. ... **Syntax**. And there's also an answer about that, but I lost it.

Comment: I have no idea what syntax you have in mind, sorry. As for answers, they are often wrong, and people often remember things wrong. Pray tell me, if you are right, **why doesn't your program work**?

Comment: @n.m. It's simple. I wanted to write an `int` on a `ByteArray`, but actually it's read/written based on an `std::uint8_t`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast#Syntax. Syntax is here.

Comment: @HydroSan: `T(s)` is the same as `(T)s`.  That's the syntax thing you are thinking of.  And `T(*s)` is the same as `(T)(*s)`.  But `T(*s)` is not the same as `*(T*)s`.  That's the mistake n.m. was pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what `memcpy` is for.

Write `T t` to `bytes`:

```
memcpy(bytes + index, &t, sizeof t);
```

Read `T` from `bytes`

```
T result;
memcpy(&result, bytes + index, sizeof result);
return result;
```

If the endianness is wrong, reverse the bytes while in the byte array.  Changing byte order inside a variable of type `T` might temporarily create illegal representations and trigger a processor fault.

Other methods such as the pointer cast you've been using in `WriteLE` can also trigger processor faults, for example due to alignment.

Just use `memcpy`.

(Even `std::copy` or `std::copy_n` are a bit questionable when it comes to strict aliasing and bitwise images, the Standard in section 3.9 uses `std::memcpy` for this exact purpose)

Comment: Thanks. :o But I'll use only primitive types on `T`, so there's no problem on reversing endianness. E.g., `unsigned`, `float`, `double`, etc.. 2) I think you did a typo on the first example (`&bytes + index` would be 2nd arg.).

Comment: The answer is rather incomplete. `memcpy` will only work for trivially copyable types.

Comment: @n.m.: Any type can be copied into a byte array (bitwise image).  Only trivial copyable types can be reconstituted from such a bitwise image and result in a usable object.  But the question only makes sense for such types in the first place.

Comment: @HydroSan: Primitive types can have trap representations, for example in your list `float` and `double`, if your system uses IEEE floating-point, will have representations categorized as "signalling NaN".  And I have the argument order (and lack of `&` in front of `bytes`) both correct.

Comment: @BenVoigt In this case I can specialize, but AFAIK float/double bits aren't affected by endianness. For this I simply used ES6's `this.DataView` class and noticed no difference on each byte value of a `float32`. Now my brother is using my laptop to play shit of "io" games (w/o counting he's older than me; he's 17), so maybe later I do this test again. Secondly, I disagree that the arguments are correct; it causes a runtime error AFAIK.

Comment: @BenVoigt I posted about the `double` endianness. Not sure if I'm 100% correct.

Comment: @HydroSan: If you are getting a runtime error, it means your pointer is wrong.  The arguments are in the correct order (destination, source, size).

Comment: It only works if I do `memcpy(&result, (&bytes[index]), sizeof(T));` on read and `memcpy((&bytes[index]), &value, sizeof(T));` on write. [Here](http://rextester.com/NSF6306). That `address + index` expression didn't work. Confused. E/ It did work now.

Comment: Thank you as hell. It'd be dangerous to test that in my laptop before.

Answer (score 0):

Posting example to comprove how there's no problem on reversing endianness of primitive types like `unsigned`, `float` and `double`, not structs and blah.

The below input will just dump the bytes of the `34.5555555559` value (in ECMAScript represented as `double` AFAIK) written on the individual big and little endiannesses.

(Note: [`float64`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float64Array) is represented as `double` in ES6.)

```
{
    const arr = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(16));

    const byte = x =>
    {
        x = x.toString(16).toUpperCase();
        return '#' + ((x.length - 1) ? x : `0${x}`);
    };

    const dump = size =>
    {
        const _arr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            _arr.push(byte( arr.getUint8(i) ));
        return _arr.join(' ');
    };

    arr.setFloat64(0, 34.5555555559, false);
    console.log(`Big-endian: ${ dump(8) }`);

    arr.setFloat64(0, 34.5555555559, true);
    console.log(`Little-endian: ${ dump(8) }`);
}
```

Output:

> Big-endian: #40 #41 #47 #1C #71 #C7 #D9 #CE
>   Little-endian: #CE #D9 #C7 #71 #1C #47 #41 #40

So you can notice the bytes were only reversed in little-endian. There's no difference on the bits. In my code I had to reverse bytes only when compiler target was big-endian based. So that's how `float`s endianness work, I think.

Comment: You totally misunderstood what I was saying.  Yes, floating-point variables have endianness, and you can store them to a byte array with the opposite endianness of your native system.  What isn't safe is reversing the endianness inside a variable of type `float` or `double` -- because when the computer looks at the variable and interprets it using native endianness, it may trigger a floating-point exception.  Do all the endianness work in the byte array copy of the `float` or `double`, not the `float` or `double` variable itself.